# the proper syntax for a function return to change a div dimensions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the height and width of a div change when i click on it by using  the return of a function, but i can't seem to figure out how to get the syntax to read correctly(ei. "400px"). Thanks in advance for any help!

```
document.getElementById("box").onclick = function() {
  function color() {
    var choice = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "pink", "gray", "brown"];
    var random = Math.random();
    random = (11 * random) / 1.25;
    random = Math.floor(random);
    return choice[random];
  }

  function size() {
    var dimensions = x + 'px';
    var x = Math.random();
    x = x * 1000;
    x = Math.floor(x);
    return dimensions;
  }

  clickedTime = Date.now();
  reactionTime = (clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000;
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = reactionTime;
  this.style.display = "none";
  this.style.background = color();
  this.style.height = size();
  this.style.height = size();
  size();

  boxReset();
}

boxReset();
```

Comment: You first do `var dimensions = x +'px';` and _then_ assign a value to `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from a certain form of `function` declaration, code is processed in the order it appears.

```
function size() {
  // x is undefined at this point and mostly useless
  var x = Math.random();
  // x is useful now
  x = x * 1000;
  // x is more useful
  x = Math.floor(x);
  // x is super useful now!
  var dimensions = x + 'px';
  // dimensions is useful now, too
  return dimensions;
}
```

Comment: There are a bunch of other issues with the code, but this solves the specific problem identified by the OP.

Comment: thanks! That makes sense. I'm still having trouble using the function to change my parameters. how do i get it to return in Quotations?

Comment: @AnthonyJohn I'm not sure what you mean. I'd suggest submitting another question. Then myself and the other users here can help you sort it out.